# Serializing nested Java Objects into json

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

There is a java object that refers to another object, and that object refers to another one. All these three objects can be serialized into json.

All classes have appropriate Jackson annotation:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class A {
    B b;
    @JsonProperty("components")
    public String getComponents() {
       /***/
    }
}

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class B {
   @JsonProperty 
   String message;
   @JsonProperty
   Long id;
   @JsonIgnore
   C c;
}

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
Class C {
   @JsonProperty 
   String param1;
   @JsonProperty
   String param2;
}
```

Currently the `getComponents` method in class A looks like this:

```
    public String getComponents() {
         JSONObject components = new JSONObject();
         components.put("b", b);
         components.put("c", c);
         return components.toString();
    }
```

For `components` property I expect to see the following in the json:

```
"components": { "b": {"message":"", id:1}, "c": {"param1":"", "param2":""}}
```

But currently it returns the reference to the objects

```
"components": { "b": "com.myproject.B@6by789ae", "c": "com.myproject.C@8io287ko"}
```

Considering that each object has the ability to be turned into json, why doesn't `JSONObject.toString` recursively loop over them and turn each into its json representation? Is there any mechanism that I use?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I found a solution. I turned `components` from `JSONObject` into `Map<String, Object>` and jackson seems to be handling the rest:

```
public Map<String, Object> getComponents() {
     Map<String, Object> components = new HashMap<>();
     components.put("b", b);
     components.put("c", c);
     return components;
}
```